# CakePHP load more results with ajax pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I was following a toturial but i'm stuck at this part:

view:

```
<?php if (!$isAjax):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastX = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var page = 1;
$(window).scroll(function () {
currentX = $(window).scrollTop();
if (currentX - lastX > 200 * page) {
lastX = currentX;
page++;
$.get('<?php echo $this->base."/products/index/page:"; ?>' + page, function(data) {
$('#prod-list').append(data);
});
}
});
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Controller:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index($page) {
$limit = 8; 
$data = $this->Products->list_products($page, $limit);
$this->set('products',$data); 
$this->set('isAjax', $this->RequestHandler->isAjax());}
```

And then model retrieves some data.
The problem is that in the view, a full html page is being append to the `prod-list` instead just the new results. How can I "fix" that?

I've read somewhere that I might need a new view to grab results and get it via ajax. It was confusing to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, load the entire page instead of part of the view?

Comment: Load the entire page (full layout with header and footer again) instead of just the results

Comment: try something like this: 

if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
     $this->disableCache(); 
            $this->layout = false;
   $this->render('ajax_index');
        }

Replace ajax_index with your view file.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Respecting AD7six note, I've changed a piece of code from a $this -> layout = false; to $this -> layout = 'ajax';.

You need to use ajax layout.

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->disableCache(); 
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->render('your_view_file');
    }
```

Comment: Ajax requests don't have a layout (or rather they do, [but it's empty](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/View/Layouts/ajax.ctp)).

Comment: Yeah you're right. But in one of the earlier projects, I use this code to load part of the HTML code, without any problems.

Comment: It won't cause any problems (even after the edit) because it's simply the same as those lines not existing.